# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having this message in an angular app after submitting the form:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined (chrome dev console tells me the error is in "elem.parent()[0].nodeName" (line 2)

```
while (!angular.equals(elem.parent(), $document) && !angular.equals(elem[0], $document[0].documentElement)) {
    if (['form', 'ngForm','userForm'].indexOf(attrs.$normalize(angular.lowercase(elem.parent()[0].nodeName))) > -1) {
        isValid = true;
        break;
    }
    formElem = elem.parent();
}
```

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: `iterElem.parent()` might be empty.

Comment: the value of iterElem.parent() is: {"0":{"0":{},"1":{"0":{},"1":{}},"2":{"0":{},"1":{}},"3":{"0":{},"1":{}},"4":{"0":{},"1":{}},"5":{"0":{},"1":{}},"6":{"0":{},"1":{}},"7":{"0":{},"1":{}},"8":{"0":{},"1":{}},"9":{},"jQuery18307779898671375001":184,"$$hashKey":"object:65"},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{"jQuery18307779898671375001":293},"context":{"jQuery18307779898671375001":293},"length":1},"context":{"jQuery18307779898671375001":293},"selector":".parent()"}

Comment: You generally run into the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined` when you try to invoke or access a property on an `undefined` object.

Comment: This might sound trivial, but...Why don't you just use the devtool in order to see what's in `iterElem.parent()`? With the chrome dev tool select with the mouse that portion of code and put the mouse over it. The devtool will evaluate the expression and you'll be able to see what's is `iterElem.parent()`. The same with the rest of the code

Comment: I tried to wrap a condition like if(iterElem.parent() !== 'undefined'){} but that didn't work. Do you know what else I could do here ?

Comment: Then checkout what `iterElem.parent()[0]` spits out. It might not be a `DOM` object that you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging the process to understand what iterElem.parent()[0] contains.
If you want to verify that the property is not undefined, try using: `angular.isUndefined(iterElem.parent()[0].nodeName)`.